# Calculating time above 24 hours in Google Sheets

Tags: time, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, duration

I have a Google doc that list a bunch of `hh:mm` durations in a column, like:

```
1:30  
1:00  
0:30
```

I am using `SUM(D2:D24)` to sum it up, and recently the total `hh:mm` went above 24 hours, so my total hours surpassed 24 hours and resultantly displays 0:15.

On Google Sheets specifically, how would I format the total Cell to allow it to go above 24:00?

Comment: Add days to your formatting?

Comment: Format as 'duration' ?

Comment: I was calculating my from - to hours but to display the correct sum of the duration I had to enter midnight or 2 in the morning as 24:00 and 26:00. Display hour changes it to 00:00 and 02:00. Now my tot sum of the duration works again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try like this:

```
=TEXT(SUM(A1:A); "[h]:mm")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I missed the overflow in a billing spreadsheet. I can literally afford to eat this month because of your answer, thanks you.

Answer (score 9):

[image: scrnsht]

Select this box were my mouse is at, then time will add up over 24 hr. (it's in dutch)

Answer (score 4):

Click on Format, select Number, then "More Formats" (at the bottom) and click on "Custom number format"
Now enter "[hh]:mm:ss" or "[hh]:mm" as preferred.

Source:
https://spreadsheetpoint.com/add-time-in-google-sheets/#Showing_Time_in_More_than_24_Hours_Format

Comment: I think its is a better solution than accepted, since it allows e.g. plotting of these values in a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Number Format to the 7th option within Time:

[image]