# Subtotal SUM does not work properly when more than 24 hours

Tags: google-sheets, sum, hour, subtotal

I have the following data in column H:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109;H3:H9999)
hours
02:15
03:30
03:30
00:15
00:15
02:00
00:30
00:30
04:00
00:30
05:45
02:15
00:30
02:00
01:00
```

[image: example]

I want to have the subtotal with function 109 (SUM ignoring hidden / filtered out rows) at the top in row 1.
However the result is: 4:45 which is not correct obviously.
Any suggestions?

I already tried to format the cell using "[h]:mm" but this did not work either.

Furthermore I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/58549941/1439628 but this only works for SUM and does not seem to work for SUBTOTAL.

Comment: It is not appropriate to post a solution to the question in that question's body, even if it is a link to your own answer to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the cells as duration and not as time, since the time formatting laps around after 24h.

[image: Example of the formatting]

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. Maybe I should have added column F and G too. These contain start time and end time. The data from column H that I provided above is calculated as difference. Now, there was one line where start time is before and end time is after midnight:

`23:30  01:30   02:00`

If I enter 25:30 instead of 01:30 everything works correctly. And it is displayed as 01:30 nevertheless.